# NumPy array size wierdness

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Should this be possible?

```
type(data): <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
size(data): 3
size(data[0]): 63
```

I thought `size' always captured every element of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.zeros(3, "O")
data[0] = np.zeros(63)
print type(data)
print np.size(data)
print np.size(data[0])
```